# php pivot как получить такой резултат

Tags: php, массивы, pivot

за акцент извините не русский

```
 $arr = [
    [
        "SchoolName" => 'Atlas Preparatory Academy',
        "schoolId" =>' 1001',
        "Supplier" => 'WEI',
        "ActivityName" => 'MacOS training',
        "Category" => 'PD',
        "Cost" => '250',
        "CostwMarkup" => '275',
        "Item Status" => 'Ready for Billing',
        "Scheduled Month" => 'Jun',
        "Completion Month" => 'Jun',
        "Markup %" => '10',
        "Markup Fee" => '25',
        "Summer School" => '0',
        "Approval Status" => 'Pending',
        "Fund Source" => '',
        "Subcategory" => '',
        "Catalog" => '',
        "Tracking Category" => 'Virtual Training Session',
        "Allocation" => 'Title I-A',
    ],
    [
        "SchoolName" => 'Atlas Preparatory Academy',
        "schoolId" => '1001',
        "Supplier" => 'WEI',
        "ActivityName" => 'Name instead of number',
        "Category" => 'PD',
        "Cost" => '240',
        "CostwMarkup" => '264',
        "Item Status" => 'Ready for Billing',
        "Scheduled Month" => 'Jun',
        "Completion Month" => 'Jul',
        "Markup %" => '10',
        "Markup Fee" => '24',
        "Summer School" =>'0',
        "Approval Status" => 'Pending',
        "Fund Source" =>' ',
        "Subcategory" => 'NS',
        "Catalog" => '',
        "Tracking Category" => '',
        "Allocation" => 'Title I-A',
    ],

    [
        "SchoolName" => 'Atlas Preparatory Academy',
        "schoolId" => '1001',
        "Supplier" => 'WEI',
        "ActivityName" => 'TEST TEST jjjjj',
        "Category" => 'PD',
        "Cost" => '240',
        "CostwMarkup" => '264',
        "Item Status" => 'Ready for Billing',
        "Scheduled Month" => 'Jun',
        "Completion Month" => 'Jun',
        "Markup %" => '10',
        "Markup Fee" =>'',
        "Summer School" => '0',
        "Approval Status" => 'Pending',
        "Fund Source" =>'',
        "Subcategory" => '',
        "Catalog" => '',
        "Tracking Category" => 'Virtual Training Session',
        "Allocation" => 'Title I-A',
    ]
];
```

нужно получить из массива такой результать на другом масиве вот картинка то что нужно
спасибо большое
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так мысли то какие-то есть у вас? некая рекурсия с фильтрацией и ссылками на исходным массив, должна быть видимо?

Comment: мысли  есть сделал кое что но так и не получится получить то что хочу (

Comment: Где эти мысли, или хотя бы их ход?

Comment: Сделал уже получился у меня вот может кому то нужно был
    foreach ($items as $key=> $item) {
            $byCategoryAndSale[$item->Allocation][$item->SchoolName][$item->Category][] = $item;
        }